# Restrict Access to DWR(Easy Ajax for Java) from URL bar

Tags: java, ajax, dwr

I am using [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html), which is commonly known as **Easy Ajax for Java** .

But it can be accessed directly via `URL bar` like this

```
http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/dwr/
```

from here I can execute each and every `Ajax Call`, which is considered as a threat to Application Security ,

Is there a way to restrict this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but here are some suggestions:

- http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/dwr/ is only available if you have set

  ```
  <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  ```

in your servlet-declaration in `web.xml`. Set param-value to false and http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/dwr/ will return a 404 (page not found).

- Even when you disable debug-mode, it is still possible to run your functions. That is why you can restrict which classes and which functions of these classes are available from the web in your `drw.xml`. For details on `dwr.xml` check the [DWR documentation](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/configuration/dwrxml/index.html)
- Keep in mind that each and every function that is publicly available should check that the user is permitted to run it. I usually create a function like this:

  ```
  private void getLoggedInUser(){
      WebContext ctx = WebContextFactory.get();
      HttpSession session=ctx.getSession();
      if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn")!=null && (Boolean)session.getAttribute("loggedIn")==true){
          if(session.getAttribute("user")!=null){
              try{
                  return (Person)session.getAttribute("user");
              }catch (ClassCastException ex){
                  return null;
              }
          }else{
              return null;
          }
      }else{
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```

then at the beginning of every function that is available through the web, i do something like

```
    Person user=getLoggedInUser();
    if(user)==null return null;
```

- Always keep in mind that javascript can be manipulated by the visitor of your site. If you publish a function through dwr, assume that it can be called by anybody. I can't stress this enough: in every function that is published through dwr, first make sure that the user is allowed to run it, then check that any arguments the user may have passed are valid.
- Update: It is also possible to restrict access to a function using [filters](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/configuration/dwrxml/filters.html).